# server does not retry dhcp after previously getting no dhcp offer

Tags: networking, dhcp, ethernet

My server gets IP address from dhcp. Sometimes the dhcp server does not respond, and my server times out (no dhcp offer, sleeping)

I thought, my server would re-try dhcp, but that does not happen.

Also, I though, it might use the last (previous) IP address that it had before. But this also does not happen.

Now my server has no IP and I cannot connect.

Is there some settings somewhere, to tell my server, it should retry dhcp when it did not get response previously ?

I have this in my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

my server is Debian 12, and my dhcp client is `isc-dhcp-client`.

Comment: It's possible that depending on whether  you are using packages `ifupdown`, `ifupdown2` or `ifupdown-ng` behavior might change. Can you state which one is installed? Anyway the setting you are asking is the DHCP lease duration: if you increase it (on the DHCP server), you allow the lease to be used for a longer time in absence of reply from the DHCP server. What's the current DHCP server lease duration?

Comment: Btw: In an (LXC container) experiment where the lease was expired and the container without address, waiting long enough (which was a short time because I set a short lease) got back the IP address. I can't reproduce your problem using `ifupdown2` (where logs can be seen using `journalctl -u networking`) nor using `ifupdown` : once I restart the DHCP server, sooner or later the sleeping dhclient adds back an address.